# Python - print depending on two variables

Tags: python, variables

so I am learning python with [dataquest.io](http://www.dataquest.io). I have just completed the beginner missions. One of the challenge questions, which I think I have accomplished (code below), is:

> Write a function that extracts the same values across years and
>   calculates the differences between consecutive values to show if
>   number of births is increasing or decreasing. For example, how did the
>   number of births on Saturday change each year between 1994 and 2003?

However, **how I can get it so that the printed result tells the reader what the time periods are**. For example, when `column == 1`, a value of 1 means January. However, when `column == 2`, a value of 1 means 'the 1st of the month'. So what value means depends on what column is. How can I convey this meaningfully to the reader, and what is this called so that I know for next time. Is is just a matter of writing a long list of `if` and `and` statements?

Thanks!

My code:

```
# year,month,date_of_month,day_of_week,births
# 0      1      2             3         4
def year_range(start_year, end_year):
    # years must be bewtween 1994 and 2003
    if end_year > 2003:
        print ("End year too high")
        return
    if start_year < 1994:
        print ("Start year too low")
        return
    # for each year from start to end
    years = []
    for x in range(end_year - start_year + 1):
        years.append(start_year + x)
    return years

def yearly_diffs(data, column, value, start_year, end_year):
    # column = 0-3
    # value depends on col, but 1-6 are always okay
    if column == 0:
        period = 'year'
    if column == 1:
        period = 'month'
    if column == 2:
        period = 'day of month'
    if column ==3:
        period = 'day of week'
    years = year_range(start_year, end_year)
    period_births = {}
    for year in years:
        period_births[year] = 0
        for x in data:
            births = x[4]
            if x[0] == year and x[column] == value:
                period_births[year] += births
    changes = {}
    for x in years:
        if x != start_year:
            changes[x] = period_births[x] - period_births[x-1]

    print ('Here are the yearly values for births for:\n{} (period)\n{} (value in period)'.format(period, value))
    return period_births, changes
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a list of lists.

```
period = [ 
           range(3000),
           [None, 'January', 'February', ...],
           [None, '1st of the month', '2nd of the month', ...],
           [None, 'Sunday', 'Monday', ...] 
         ]

print(period[column][value])
```

The `column` variable chooses the appropriate inner list, and the `value` variable indexes it. No `if`s required. The `None`s at the front account for the fact that your values start at 1 rather than 0. The `range(3000)` deals with the years.